# ¿Cual es la función equivalente a la función "lastval()" de PostgreSQL en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

¿Qué función reemplaza al `lastval()` de PostgreSQL en MySQL, para crear una nueva columna con el último id?

Ejemplo en PostgreSQL:

```
select lastval()
```

Pero, ¿cómo puedo hacer lo mismo en MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

En PostgreSQL, la función [lastval()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) te permite encontrar el valor auto-generado más reciente de una columna `SERIAL` en el contexto de la sesión corriente.

```
select lastval()
```

En MySQL, el equivalente es la función [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), que funciona de forma similar, pero con columnas de tipo `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

```
select last_insert_id()
```

Answer (score 1):

En MySQL no existe una función especifica que te obtenga el ultimo valor, pero puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Ordenar el id de forma decendente.
2. utilizar `limit` para obtener el primer valor.

**Este es un ejemplo de como funcionaría:**

```
create table tbl (
  id int not null primary key,
  texto varchar(50) not null
);

insert into tbl (id, texto) values (1, 'aaa');
insert into tbl (id, texto) values (5, 'eee');
insert into tbl (id, texto) values (2, 'bbb');
insert into tbl (id, texto) values (4, 'ddd');

select *
  from tbl
 order by id desc
 limit 1;
```

**Resultado:**

```
id   texto
--   -----
5    eee
```

Comment: Hola @iuninefrendor. Toma en cuenta que sí existe una función para obtener el último valor. Pero aunque no existiera, usar `LIMIT` o `MAX`, o cualquier otra técnica similar, puede devolverte valores inesperados si otra sesión concurrente está haciendo inserts a la misma tabla.